# ParseError: Unexpected token = when trying to save in google Apps Script editor

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I reduced the issue to this simple bit of code:

```
class X {
  static a = 5;
}
```

I don't know why this is a problem.  It seems to be valid code.  Any ideas?

[image: Image of error]

Comment: I notice that static methods do _not_ throw a GAS syntax error (whereas static fields do). I didn't see anything pertinent in the [V8 runtime](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/v8-runtime) notes.

Comment: So this is a bug then @andrewjames?

Comment: I don't know. It could have some other explanation - maybe they are disallowed in GAS, for some reason. I did not see anything obvious in the Google [issue tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com). If you don't get an answer here, you could open a ticket.

Comment: As this seems to be a bug, I've reported it here:  https://issuetracker.google.com/u/1/issues/194120497

Comment: There is a reply to your bug report ("won't fix"). I think it would be worth copying their notes & workarounds into an answer, here. Because you found the problem, asked the question, and opened the ticket, would you like to do that?

Comment: I'm closing this, as the bug report in the duplicate is more relevant and is still open.

Comment: Although Google Apps Script doesn't support static class fields, it does support static methods/getters/setters, so you can do this: `class X {
  static get a(){ return this._a || 0 }
  static set a(value){ this._a = value }
}`, then you can get/set `X.a` as usual.

Answer (score 11):

*Response from Google*:

---

Apps Script V8 runtime supports EMCA2015 standards which mean static class properties are not supported at the moment. There are two workarounds available:

1 - Assign the property to the class:

```js
// Caused an error
class MyClass {
  static a = 1;
}
```

```js
// ECMA2015 compatible
class MyClass {}
MyClass.a = 1;
```

2 - Develop the Apps Scripts with Clasp: https://github.com/google/clasp which also supports TypeScript and many other new features.

---

Full details are in [this ticket](https://issuetracker.google.com/u/1/issues/194120497).

Comment: Static property throws the same error even with Clasp (2.4.2).

Answer (score 1):

No static variables, but static functions are supported. So, technically you could use this:

```
class X {
  static a(){return 5;}
}
X.a();
```

It's not a variable.. but oh well, gets the job done!