# Google Sheets `setValues` does not use `toString()` when showing object instances

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script

When using `setValues()` on a collection of values, some of which are object instances, it doesn't call `toString()` to get the value to be shown but inspects the contents of the objects instead, a view more suitable for a developer than an end user.

```
class Sample {
  [Symbol.toPrimitive](hint) {
    Logger.log('symbol')
    return `${a}-${b}`;
  }
  constructor(a, b) {
    this.a = a;
    this.b = b;
  }
  toString() {
    Logger.log('toString')
    return `${a}-${b}`;
  }
  valueOf() {
    Logger.log('valueOf')
    return `${a}-${b}`;
  }
}

function test() {
  const sample = new Sample(1, 2);
  SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet().getRange(1, 1).setValue(sample)
}

// expected value in cell:
1-2

// actual value
{b=2.0, a=1.0}
```

In this example I just used a single value so I might as well call `setValue(sample.toString())` but in the real life case I have a matrix of objects derived from various classes and primitive values rendered with a call to `setValues()` (plural)

As you can see in the `Sample` class, I have provided all the methods to render the object contents as a primitive I could think of.  None of them are called.

I would like to avoid pre-processing the matrix to get the values before calling `setValues()` but, mostly, I think that gSheets seems to be acting as a developer tool, which shouldn't be the default.

Comment: Are these all classes that you write? Can you show an example of the matrix you are passing? And why would preprocessing be a bad thing?

Answer (score 2):

In your example, it's normal for the script to output `{ a: 1, b: 2 }` since the constructor method creates object instances and by default, this is as per documentation, [setValue(value)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setvaluevalue) and [setValues(values)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setvaluesvalues) are also `object` types, making them versatile, and putting them on a cell in a spreadsheet would output the same.

To get your desired output, either convert the object instance into a string by using `toString()`, use `static methods` as suggested by the other answer, or use a `getter method` to return it.

Plus, don't think that `gSheets seems to be acting as a developer tool, which shouldn't be the default.` because as an online spreadsheet platform, it's only displaying what's being thrown to it by Google Apps Script, which for me is a developer tool.

Answer (score 1):

#### **SUGGESTION:**

You may use the `Static method` that are defined on the class itself
like this:

```
class Sample {

   static convertToString(a,b) {
    Logger.log('toString')
    return `${a}-${b}`;
  }

}

function test() {
  const sample = Sample.convertToString(1, 2);
  
  SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet().getRange(1, 1).setValue(sample)
}
```

RESULT:

[image]

With this, you can put the objects neatly on the class itself to avoid pre-process and

just like in javascript, you cannot call a static method on an object, only on an object class.

*Ref:* [How to use static method in google app script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69202290/how-to-use-static-method-in-google-app-script)

Comment: Sorry, but that is not the point.  I already have a toString() method that does not require me to pass any arguments and know how to print that instance.

Comment: I apologize if this does not answer your concern. Can you please elaborate and clarify your comment above?

Comment: Using a `static` method seems not to address the issue. You have an object instance on which you can call `toString` to turn it into the string. This works already, but the OP is trying to avoid that. Creating a static method means you are still having to call the method yourself, but with even more cumbersome syntax.

Comment: As mentioned by Drew, what the OP is getting is an expected behavior thus what he can do as an alternative solution or as a suggestion is by using `static method` or  a `getter method` to return it.

Answer (score 0):

Issue opened with Google:

https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/324780198

No answer yet